# populate second dropdown value based on selection from first dropdown in react antd table

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a table which dispalys two dropdown values.I want to get a second drop dropdown to populate based on which option is clicked from first dropdown.In my console  everything is fine,but second dropdown always showing empty

below table displays the list of company related information, while we are trying to edit a company related information in table, Changing the company id, needs to fetch and populate branch dropdown associated with the changed company value

Here is the code for two dropdown values

```
var companyData =[];
  var branchData =[];

const EditableCell = ({
  title,
  editable,
  children,
  dataIndex,
  record,
  inputType,
  ...restProps
}) => {
  const [editing, setEditing] = useState(false);
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  
  
 **axios.get('http://localhost:8000/masters/selectcompany' 'this url to select the company').then((result) => {
    companyData = result.data;
})
 const handleChangeCompanyId = (e) => {    
  var value = e;
axios.get('http://localhost:8000/masters/branchselect?companyid='+value  'this url will retrieve the branches ').then((result) => {
    branchData=result.data;
  
})}
 
const BranchSelect = () => {
  return (
    <Select
    placeholder="branch_code"
    onChange={handleChange}
    allowClear
   
  >{branchData.map(branch =>
    <Option value={branch.value}>{branch.name}</Option>
  )}
   </Select>
  )
}
     
const CompSelect = () => {
  return (
    <Select
    onChange={handleChangeCompanyId}
  >{companyData.map(company =>
    <Option value={company.value}>{company.name}</Option>
  )}
  </Select>
  )
}**

  const inputNode =  inputType === "branchselect" ? <BranchSelect /> :inputType=== "Compselect" ? <CompSelect /> :null;
   
  useEffect(() => {
    if (editing) {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    }
  }, [editing]);
let childNode = children;

  if (editable) {
    childNode = editing ? (
      <Form.Item
        name={dataIndex}
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: `${title} is required.`,
          },
        ]}
      >
        {inputNode}
       </Form.Item>
    ) : (
      <div >
          {(record[dataIndex] ?  record[dataIndex] :  inputNode)}
       </div>
    );
  }

 return <td {...restProps}>{childNode}</td>;
};
```